# Can anyone suggest/recommend books for Jmeter for better handson

Tags: jmeter

I am a automation tester want to learn Jmeter. I have searched some materials on the net but it will be great for me to find some books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not a lot of jMeter books, this one seems the most recommended: https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/jmeter-cookbook

[According to BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-users-one-book-you-must-read-year) a must read:

> JMeter Users: The One Book You MUST Read This Year

Comment: Other book we would advise as it is written by 3 JMeter developers and committers : https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops/

Answer (score 3):

The best place to start with are official:

- [Getting Started](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)
- [User's Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html)
- [Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Going forward you may find [The Ultimate JMeter Resource List](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ultimate-jmeter-resource-list) useful.